# Unable to change resolution on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, intel, kde5

I use a laptop that has an Intel graphics card. I also use Kubuntu 16.04 with Plasmashell 5.5.5. When I try to change the resolution I get a black screen. It does not matter if I use the GUI, or xrandr -s WIDTHxHEIGHT.

xrandr givesthe following output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Anyone know what's happening?